# Create children inside an existing array

Tags: php, arrays

Let me get this really quickly, here is my source array:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [1] => Array (
            [id] => 1
            [category] => Men
            [items] => Array (
                [0] => Array (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => Shirt
                    [price] => 21.8
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    [1] => Array (
        [1] => Array (
            [id] => 2
            [category] => Men
            [items] => Array (
                [0] => Array (
                    [id] => 2
                    [name] => Trousers
                    [price] => 10.9
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    [2] => Array (
        [1] => Array (
            [id] => 3
            [category] => Men
            [items] => Array (
                [0] => Array (
                    [id] => 3
                    [name] => Hat
                    [price] => 1.9
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    [3] => Array (
        [2] => Array (
            [id] => 4
            [category] => Women
            [items] => Array (
                [0] => Array (
                    [id] => 4
                    [name] => Bra
                    [price] => 24.5
                    )
                )
            )
        )
        .
        .
        .
```

What I want to achieve now is to combine `items` by similar `category` like this:

```
{
    "1": {
        "id": 1,
        "category": "Men",
        "items": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Shirt",
                "price": "5:52"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Trousers",
                "price": "3:01"
            },
        ]
    },
    .
    .
    .
```

I've tried several approach with parentId and stuff, but couldn't get around it.

Any idea how to get this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a first attempt:

```
$output = array();

foreach ($source as $data) {
    foreach ($data as $categoryId => $item) {
        if (!isset($output[$categoryId])) {
            $output[$categoryId] = array(
                'id'       => $categoryId,
                'category' => $item['category'],
                'items'    => array(),
            );  
        }   

        $output[$categoryId]['items'] = array_merge(
            $output[$categoryId]['items'],
            $item['items']
        );
    }   
}
```

You may need to handle the items differently, depending on how many items are in each element of your source array. I'm also not quite sure what you're getting at with the price value in your expected output, so you may need to elaborate on that.

Codepad: http://codepad.org/tY15P0Qa

Comment: Thanks! This one really works. The price value is just dummy, no need to worry about it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this, where `$catalog_item`is your initial array and `$new_catalog`your desired array :

```
    $new_catalog = array( ) ;
    foreach( $catalog_item as $grouping ) {
        $mixed_cat_item = array_pop( $grouping ) ;
        if( ! array_key_exists( $mixed_cat_item[ 'id' ], $new_catalog) {
           $new_catalog[ $mixed_cat_item[ 'id' ] ] = array( 'id' => $mixed_cat_item[ 'id' ], 'category' => $mixed_cat_item[ 'category' ], 'items' => array( ) ) ;
        }
        $item = array_pop( $mixed_cat_item[ 'items' ] ) ;
        $new_catalog[ 'id' ][ 'items' ][ ] = $item ;
    }
```